# LibGDX fonts with mipmapping drawn as black squares

Tags: java, libgdx, mipmaps

I've encountered some issues with LibGDX's filtering. Fonts work fine without using mipmaps, but when I add them the text renders as a series of black boxes.

Here's the method I use to generate a font.

```
public static BitmapFont generateFont(String fontPath, int size, String chars){
    FileHandle fontFile = Gdx.files.internal(fontPath);
    FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(fontFile);
    FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter params = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
    params.size = size;
    params.magFilter = TextureFilter.MipMapLinearLinear;
    params.minFilter = TextureFilter.MipMapLinearLinear;
    params.characters = chars;
    BitmapFont f = generator.generateFont(params);
    generator.dispose();
    return f;
}
```

Without mipmaps:
[image: No mipmaps]

With mipmaps:
[image: With mipmaps]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `params.genMipMaps = true` before generating your font.

Also, it doesn't make sense to use mip-maps for your mag filter. Not sure if it could cause problems on some devices, but I would just set it to Linear.